# .bash_profile does not work with docker php image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

There is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/php/
FROM php:5.5.23-fpm

USER www-data

ADD .bash_profile /var/www/.bash_profile

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN source /var/www/.bash_profile
```

Then after container built I run `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bash` I did not see my aliases defined into `/var/www/.bash_profile`. But if I execute `source /var/www/.bash_profile` manually – everything is ok.

The same problem described here: https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/896 but no answer.

Comment: Your Dockerfile has no `CMD`or `ENTRYPOINT` and  you do not show your `docker run` command, as `docker exec`connects to a running container

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because those (ie 'RUN' and 'SHELL') are build instructions. When you execute `docker run` the `ENTRYPOINT` and `COMMAND` are being executed instead.

`docker exec` however just enters into an existing container's namespace and executes a command. So in your case it just runs `bash`. That's why you have to source your profile again.

UPDATE:

This snippet is from `man bash`:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell  is  started,  bash  reads  and  executes  commands  from
>          /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist.

So in your case if you change the file name to `~/.bashrc` probably works

Comment: Yeap, `docker exec` runs a `bash` from user `www-data` (home dir is `/var/www`). In this home dir i put the `.bash_profile` file. I think that it have to source automatically, is not it?

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends first if you have defined `/var/www/www-data` as  home path for` www-data` user and second how you invoke bash. Read the update above.

Comment: So sad, because the answer was so easy! Thanks a lot! What works.

Answer (score 11):

Had a similar issue and the easiest solution was to use the -l option to bash to make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell.

```
docker run --rm -it $IMAGE /bin/bash -l
```

bash will then read in ~/.bash_profile

Comment: same works for `docker exec -it $IMAGE /bin/bash -l`, i.e. it will also source automatically ~/.bash_profile, which is a difference of login shell vs. non-login shell, explained [here]( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.
Dockerfile relevant snippet:

```
RUN scripts/script1.sh
RUN scripts/script2.sh
```

Snippet from `scripts/script1.sh`

```
echo "TEST_ENV=Hello" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Snippet from `scripts/script2.sh`

```
echo $TEST_ENV
```

The `echo` statement in `script2` printed nothing, that is `script2` could not see `TEST_ENV` variable at all.

So, it turns out that every `RUN` instruction is executed in its own shell. So, the environment variable will only be visible in the shell where `source ~/.bashrc` is executed, which is the shell in which `script1` ran. For it to be visible in `script2`'s shell, a exclusive `source ~/.bashrc` has to be executed from `script2`.

In case an environment variable is required to be present within the running container, then the code that is run as part of Docker's `ENTRYPOINT` or `COMMAND` should source the `.bashrc` file. Logging into the running container with `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash`, will demonstrate that the environment variable is indeed set.